# Akka .NET PipeTo() with ContinueWith()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, akka.net

[The Top 7 Mistakes Newbies Make with Akka.NET](https://petabridge.com/blog/top-7-akkadotnet-stumbling-blocks/) explains why using async/await within an actor is often a bad idea:

> [...] we see end users develop lots of nested async / await operations inside an individual message handler. There’s a cost overlooked by most users to doing this: the actor can’t process any other messages between each await operation because those awaits are still part of the “1 message at a time” guarantee for the original message!

Yet in [Unit 3 Lesson 4](https://github.com/petabridge/akka-bootcamp/blob/master/src/Unit-3/lesson4/README.md) of the Petabridge Akka .NET Bootcamp, this example is considered okay:

```
// asynchronously download the image and pipe the results to ourself
_httpClient.GetAsync(imageUrl).ContinueWith(httpRequest =>
{
    var response = httpRequest.Result;

    // successful img download
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var contentStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        try
        {
            contentStream.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            return new ImageDownloadResult(image,
                response.StatusCode, contentStream.Result);
        }
        catch //timeout exceptions!
        {
            return new ImageDownloadResult(image, HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
        }
    }

    return new ImageDownloadResult(image, response.StatusCode);
},
  TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)
 .PipeTo(Self);
```

The way I understand this, the actor will not be able to process any other messages until `GetAsync()` AND `ContinueWith()` are done, which is exactly the problem `PipeTo()` was trying to avoid.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async API call inside an actor and exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550275/async-api-call-inside-an-actor-and-exceptions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is happening is that since `GetAsync()` is not awaited, the whole thing fires off asynchronously and does not block execution.

While all this is happening, the actor is free to process additional messages.

Comment: Yes agreed, after reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550275/async-api-call-inside-an-actor-and-exceptions. Also think this is a possible duplicate

Answer (score 3):

`TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` means the `ContinueWith` will run sinchronously with the code that transitions the task to complete ([TaskContinuationOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)).

The code in the example will fire the task, setup `ContinueWith()` and `PipeTo()`, and return. The actor is free to receive new messages, and when the task completes, `PipeTo()` will send it the resulting message.

As Gigi mentioned, if the Task were to be awaited in the actor, then it would be blocked.

It might help to think that `ContinueWith()` also returns a task, and that's what `PipeTo()` operates on.

This is the PipeTo extention in [Akka.net Github](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/3f924fda8d6ca55c5af90a710d23be8ce36d5c7a/src/core/Akka/Actor/PipeToSupport.cs):

```
    public static Task PipeTo<T>(this Task<T> taskToPipe, ICanTell recipient, IActorRef sender = null, Func<T, object> success = null, Func<Exception, object> failure = null)
    {
        sender = sender ?? ActorRefs.NoSender;
        return taskToPipe.ContinueWith(tresult =>
        {
            if (tresult.IsCanceled || tresult.IsFaulted)
                recipient.Tell(failure != null
                    ? failure(tresult.Exception)
                    : new Status.Failure(tresult.Exception), sender);
            else if (tresult.IsCompleted)
                recipient.Tell(success != null
                    ? success(tresult.Result)
                    : tresult.Result, sender);
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
```